# Is WebView / WebScriptObject evaluateWebScript thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, webview

Is it safe to send `[myWebScriptObject evaluateWebScript:@"someJavascript()"]` from any thread? Specifically I would like to send callbacks into the `WebView` for async I/O completion. For example AFNetworking web requests.